# Wordpress get metabox info for selected custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a form, created as a plugin in wordpress. In the form is a drop down select menu that is populated with all entries from a custom post type called 'singers'.

i.e. "singer 1, singer 2, singer 3"

In this custom post type, each singer has meta box info, the info I'm interested in is 'singer_gender'. When a singer is selected, I want to pass a variable into a hidden field on that form with either "male" or "female"

So, for example, if Singer 1 is selected, and is male, my form would have the following hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="singer_gender" id="singer_gender" value="<?php echo singer_gender; ?>" />
```

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: You could do this with javascript and / or ajax - but why not do this at the point when you handle the form submit? Check the value of the drop down then get the meta value for that and there is your value to use as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You would use [`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to retrieve values entered in a meta box.

If `singer_gender` is the meta box key, your code might look like this:

```
<?php
  global $post;
  $single_gender = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'singer_gender', true);
?>

<input type="hidden" name="singer_gender" id="singer_gender" value="<?php echo $singer_gender; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the gender inside a data value on the options of the select.

Like this:

```js
$('#person').change(function(){
 var gender = $(this).find('option:checked').attr('data-gender');
    $('#gender_hidden').val(gender);
    $('#gender').val(gender);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="hidden" id="gender_hidden" />
    <input type="text" id="gender" />
    <select id="person" onchange="change(this);">
        <option value="Person_1" data-gender="male">Person 1</option>
        <option value="Person_2" data-gender="female">Person 2</option>
        <option value="Person_3" data-gender="male">Person 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

To generate the HTML for that use [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type'=>'people');

$people = WP_Query($args);
if ($people->have_posts()) ?>
    <input id="gender" name="gender" />
    <select name="person">
        <?php while ($people->have_posts()){ $people->the_post();
            global $post;
            $name = get_the_title();
            $slug = $post->post_name;
            $gender = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gender', true);
        ?>
        <option data-gender="<?php echo $gender; ?>" value="<?php echo $slug; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
<?php }
```